# Understanding $AB$ as a transform of matrix $A$ by matrix $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, linear-transformations, intuition

Given matrix $A$ and vector $x$, we can view $A$ as a linear transform, so that $Ax$ means $x$ transformed by $A$.  The powerful insight is that $A$ transforms basis vector $e_j$ to $A_{:j}$ (the $j^{th}$ col of $A$): we can read the transform's definition right out of the matrix encoding!  $A$'s definition, as a linear transform of $x$, is therefore quite explicit.

Although $AB$ isn't a linear transform of $B$, we can still view this as $A$ "acting on" $B$, transforming each col of $B$ by this linear transform.

Now, we can *also* view $AB$ as $B$ acting on $A$.  That is, $B$ transforms each *row* of $A$ by a linear transform.  I would like to understand the nature of that transform (that is, of how $B$ transforms $A$).

**Question:** How can we describe the transformation that $B$ does to $A$?

My attempt so far is below.  I'd appreciate verification, critique, or other approaches.

If the standard basis is $\{e_n\}$, let $\{t_n\}$ be the transpose of $\{e_n\}$.  That is, $\{t_n\}$  is the basis of **row vectors** that matrix $A$ is encoded in (whereas $\{e_n\}$ is the basis of col vectors).  *Is there a name for this row basis? I couldn't find a reference for it.*  Then $B_{i:}$ (that is, the $i^{th}$ row of $B$) shows the transform of $t_i$ when multiplied by $B$.  That is, $$t_i B = B_{i:}$$

$B$ transforms $A$ by replacing each row of $A$ with the linear transform thus encoded.

(Justification: $(x^\top A^\top)\top = Ax$, so if left multiplication by a matrix transforms cols of $x$ or $B$ according to the cols of $A$, then right multiplication by a matrix must transform *rows* of $x^\top$ or $A$ by the *rows* of $B$.)

Is this correct? If not, what is the correct way to understand $B$ acting on $A$ (or right multiplication by a matrix in general).

Comment: But $AB$ *is* a linear transformation on $B$:  $A(B+C)=AB+AC$ and $A(cB)=cAB$.  You just consider the domain to be the vector space of all $n \times n$ matrices $B$.

Comment: @Randall Great point.  Can that perspective be used to consider $AB$ a linear transformation on $A$? How does the matrix encoding of $B$ relate to the linear transformation performed by $B$ (that is, that $B$ does to a matrix on its _left_)?

Comment: Yes, it's just a different linear transformation.