# Can right multiplication by a matrix be viewed as a linear transformation? How?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, intuition

> The most important use of matrices lies in representing linear transformations on a vector space...
>
> A matrix represents the transformation which takes the first basis vector into first column of the matrix, second basis vector into the second column of the matrix, j-th basis vector into j-th column
>
> --[Professor D. Kleitman, MIT](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/18/18.013a/textbook/HTML/chapter32/section05.html)

The above applies to left multiplication by a matrix $Ax$.  Is there an analog for right multiplication $yA$ (with $y$ being a row vector)?

Can we use the above to see $AB$ as a transformation of $B$ by $A$ *and* as a transformation of $A$ by $B$?

(See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4659755/understanding-ab-as-a-transform-of-matrix-a-by-matrix-b) which is related, but not as direct.)

---

### Update

*Thank you MJD for comments.*

I believe the correct answer is: $yB$ is the transformation which takes the first *row basis vector* into the first *row* of $B$, the second *row basis vector* into the second *row* of $B$, and, in general, viewing row vector $y$ as a linear combination of row vectors, takes $y$ to the corresponding linear combination of the rows of $B$.

A *row basis* would be the transpose of the standard basis; I'm surprised I can't find any reference for this idea.

This implies that $AB$ is both:

1. A transform of $B$ by $A$, replacing each col of $B$ with the transform defined by $A$ on it: $B_{:j} \mapsto A(B_{:j})$
2. *And*, a transform of $A$ by $B$, replacing each *row* of $A$ with the transform defined by $B$ on it: $A_{i:} \mapsto B(A_{i:})$

The miraculous thing is that *for any two matrices, in any space, if $AB$ is defined, **both transforms equal to the same thing***.  How do we explain that?

Is the above correct?

Comment: Does it help to observe that $AB={(B^TA^T)}^T$?

Comment: @MJD Thanks! Edited - can you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrixover a field $F$. Let $U$ be the vector space of all $p \times m$ matrices over $F$.Let $V$ be the vector space of all $p \times n$ matrices over $F$.Then the map $U \to V$ defined by $C \mapsto CA, C \in U$ is a linear transformation from $U$ to $V$. In particular, if $p=1$, we have the linear transformation from the vector  space of row vectors with $p$ entries to the vector  space of row vectors with $n$ entries.